# mysql package isn't loading in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

Have the following code -

```
    var http = require('http');
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    // Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
    var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.end("Hello World\n");
    });

    // Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
    server.listen(8000);

    // Put a friendly message on the terminal
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

When I'm trying to run I'm getting the following error -

> Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'

Though I have mysql module installed.
Here is something weird, I did installed it with npm install mysql but...

> npm ls

returns

> └── (empty)

Running

> "npm prefix"

returns /home/user, while

> npm config get prefix

returns

> /home/user/.node

Something that makes it even weirder is the fact that that I have the mysql package both in ~/.node/lib/node_modules/mysql and in ~/.npm/mysql/2.3.2/package (Also, .npm contains more packages)

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Where is the script located? `require()` will only find packages that are [installed relative to the script](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders). And, globally installed packages [are not included in that](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html). By design, those are only available to the command line, not to `require()`.

Comment: try: npm install mysql -g

Comment: Did you install `mysql` via npm with `-g` (e.g. `npm install mysql -g`) ? If you do `npm install mysql` and `npm ls` in the same directory, you should see it show up in the list.

Comment: Well, turns out that installing mysql with -g cuased the problem. I've installed it again without the -g and it worked